# batch script checking multiple strings from text file

Tags: batch-file

### Here is my requirement:

First we need check the process name (so parse as I explain to verify if `processName` get the value "convert-c0").
Then you check first the loop crashing status.(by parsing as said before)

- If it’s true, stop script and send alert
- If it’s false resume the following step
  Then check status value (by parsing as said before)
- If it’s different from “started” then send alert

### Log file snippet:

### I tried this:

```
findstr convert-c0 C:\Users\A637122\Desktop\custlog.txt > output.txt

FOR /F "tokens=2" %%a IN (C:\Users\A637122\Desktop\output.txt) DO (echo %%a | findstr /I false)
IF %errorlevel%==0 (
echo loopALERT > C:\Users\A637122\Desktop\monitor.txt
GOTO EXT
 ELSE (
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%b IN (C:\Users\A637122\Desktop\output.txt) DO (echo %%b | findstr /I started)
IF %errorlevel%==1 (echo statALERT > C:\Users\A637122\Desktop\monitor.txt)
)
)
:EXT
```

--

Please suggest. Thank you.
Regards,
PK

Comment: What is your question? You are missing a parentheses with your `ELSE`.  It should be `)  ELSE (`

Comment: You can remove the last right parentheses as well.  Also, when you are inside a code block, you need to use delayed expansion with your variables.  So currently your `%errorlevel%` variable will not populate correctly.  But you would not even need to use.  Just use conditional execution instead. `(echo %%b | findstr /I started || echo statALERT > C:\Users\A637122\Desktop\monitor.txt)`